# ContourPlot not evaluating correctly

Tags: plotting, evaluation

When I try to plot an evaluated equation with contour plot in Mathematica 9, but do so with a variable, the plot is empty, but when I input the evaluated equation itself, the ContourPlot plots correctly.  Everything worked fine in Mathematica10.

Here's my equations

```
table2b = 
  Evaluate[
    Table[
      Evaluate@eq2, {P, {-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}}, {n, {.1, .1}}, {α, {1, 1}}, {ρ, {.1, .1}}]];

plotpoints = 200;

fulltable = Union[Flatten[table2b]]

ContourPlot[fulltable, {p, -1, 15}, {q, -100, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> plotpoints, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True]
```

This gives me an empty box.  However, when I plug in directly the evaluated version of fulltable, everything plots correctly.  The evaluated fulltable is below.

```
{-4 + p - q == 
  1 + (1. (p - q))/q - 0.464159 (q/(p - q))^(1/3), -2 + p - q == 
  1 + (1. (p - q))/q - 0.464159 (q/(p - q))^(1/3), 
 p - q == 1 + (1. (p - q))/q - 0.464159 (q/(p - q))^(1/3), 
 2 + p - q == 1 + (1. (p - q))/q - 0.464159 (q/(p - q))^(1/3), 
 4 + p - q == 1 + (1. (p - q))/q - 0.464159 (q/(p - q))^(1/3)}
```

Comment: You haven't included the definition of eq2 (please, do so), but I note that you use a capital P in the Table, whereas you use a lowercase p in the plot. Mathematica is case sensitive... BTW All those evaluates shouldn't be necessary (generally).

Comment: Try using `CubeRoot` or `Surd` instead of `^(1/3)`.  The one-third power may be giving you complex values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat sure that this issue depends on the *Mathematica* version you are using. What you have to understand is that `ContourPlot` has the attribute `HoldAll` which indicates that arguments like your `fulltable` are not evaluated to the list of equations it contains.

Since this leads to empty plots which give new users a hard time, I guess Wolfram included some more sophisticated tests in newer versions of *Mathematica* to see whether users provided a variable that contains the list of equations.

The conclusion is that the following code works fine in V10, but does show an empty plot in V8.

```
expr = {Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2};
ContourPlot[expr, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

To make it work in V8, please wrap an `Evaluate` around `expr` in the contour plot. This should solve the issue with your real problem too then.

Comment: Somewhere between V10 and V12 things changed again.  In V12 one needs `ContourPlot[Evaluate[expr],...]`.